# Как узнать в таблице: "users" login. А потом узнать id по этому login. Используя RedBeanPHP

Tags: php

Мой код выглядит сейчас вот так:

```
$login = $_SESSION['logged_user'];
$send = R::find('users', 'login = ?', [$login]);
$send = R::load('users', $_SESSION['logged_user']);
$send->steam = $steamprofile['steamid'];
R::store($send);
```

Comment: а что в приведенном коде происходит?..

Comment: Так если у Вас id в сессии храниться, зачем Вам его из БД брать? Можно одним запросом сделать. Что-то вроде `select id, login where id = $_SESSION['logged_user'] from table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно одним SQL запросом вытащить все данные о конкретном пользователе, и позже ими манипулировать

`` $logged_user = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '".$_SESSION['logged_user']."' "); ``

Затем обращаться хоть к id хоть к другим данным

```
echo $logged_user['id'];
echo $logged_user['age'];
echo $logged_user['some'];
```

Удачи!)

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in D:\OpenServer\domains\edrenbaton\index.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\OpenServer\domains\edrenbaton\index.php on line 17
(Строчка 17 это код который вы указали выше)

Comment: это нормально если у вас подключение к Базе данных реализовано иным методом) Там же в теле ошибки написано, что запрос пытался исходить от несуществующего элемента) Вы как подключаетесь к БД? Не просто копируйте код, а действуйте по аналогии) Жду вашего ответа)

Comment: У вас есть дискорд? Мне не удобно здесь общаться. Rysik5318#7967

Comment: require 'libs/rb.php';
R::setup( 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test',
 'Rysik5318', 'password' );